# iPhone PNG image displays differently in Android TextView drawable

Tags: iphone, android, graphics

I have a PNG file formatted for the iPhone I used in a TextView drawable.  The image is just two words in black text on a white background, when you view it.  On the iPhone it shows as two words in white text on a black background.  On the Android it shows as two words in black text on a transparent background.

Can someone tell me how to make the Android image show as white text on a black background by configuring the Android TextView?  I'd like to save time from creating new PNG files.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iPhone uses a non-standard PNG format. Xcode will automatically create files changed to this format for you when it compiles your app. What you should do is not grab the PNG from your app resources bundle and instead use the original PNG you created in your image editing software. [See this blog post for more details.](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/iphone-optimized-pngs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using the "same" image? If the image is "black text on a white background" how does the iphone invert it to white on black?

can you post the image on here so we can see it?

And yes, you need to mark answers accepted or you will probably find it hard to get anything ever answered.